# quartz job running for every 1 minute though I configured for 5 minutes

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have configured the quartz job for every 5 minutes in xml file which is included in `applicationcontext.xml`

```
<property name="cronExpression" value=" 0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *" />
```

But it is running for every 1 minute

Does anyone faced similar issue? let me know incase of any further details

Comment: Please post your applicationContext.xml.

Answer (score 0):

0 0/5 * * * ? worked for me instead of      0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *